# Possible to do recursive definitions with unboxed vectors?

Tags: haskell, recursion, vector

I would like to generate an unboxed vector recursively. As a simple example:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V

fib :: V.Vector Int
fib = V.generate 10 f
  where
    f 0 = 0
    f 1 = 1
    f x = (fib V.! (x - 1)) + (fib V.! (x - 2))
```

the function correctly generates the fibonacci sequence. However, if I use `Data.Vector.Unboxed` instead, the code will hang. I understand the reason why this is, but I'd still like to be able to do a recursive definition and get the speed of an unboxed vector. Are there any possibilities in doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to use an *unboxed mutable* vector and *freeze* it once done with construction:

```
import Control.Monad.ST (runST)
import Control.Monad (forM_, ap)
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as M

fib :: Int -> U.Vector Int
fib s = runST $ M.new s >>= ap ((>>) . forM_ [0..s - 1] . f) U.unsafeFreeze
    where
    f v 0 = M.write v 0 0
    f v 1 = M.write v 1 1
    f v i = do
        a <- M.read v (i - 1)
        b <- M.read v (i - 2)
        M.write v i (a + b)
```

Answer (score 5):

`constructN` does what you want, even in the unboxed case. Below, `v` is the vector prefix built so far, and `f v` returns the next element.

Optimal O(N) complexity.

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V

fib :: V.Vector Int
fib = V.constructN 10 f
  where
    f v = case V.length v of
            0 -> 0
            1 -> 1
            n -> (v V.! (n - 1)) + (v V.! (n - 2))
```

Comment: what if f(n) is not a function of _only_ previous indices 0..n-1? say, you are traversing a graph and at each node the indices of interest are adjacent nodes' indices

Comment: @behzad.nouri Sure, in the general case `constructN` is not enough, but I guess it covers many cases, in practice. In the most general case, I'd use boxed vectors. If I knew how many steps are required to reach fixed point (which might be far less than the length of the vector, in general), I might also consider mutable vectors as in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of to do this is to generate a lazy recursive list, and then convert that to an unboxed vector.

The standard baffling incantation

```
fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

will give you an infinite list of Fibonacci numbers. You can then build an unboxed list from that, which will have fast indexing thereafter.

Sure, it's not actually using the vector for *computing* the Fibonacci numbers. But it's not doing O(n) indexing over the linked list either, so it should be reasonably fast.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I'm actually implementing a dynamic programming algorithm such that when I complete calculating vector I also get my answer and am done with it. So in my actual case this won't be very useful. But in general I'd say it's a good approach.

Comment: @ritzymon In that case, are you sure you want an unboxed vector at all? Standard dynamic programming techniques using lists are often quite performant -- in particular they generally will not even store the whole list in memory at any point.